# Nuxt auth module with Spotify

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, spotify

I am trying to connect to a couple social services through a Nuxt app and was starting by trying Spotify oauth2.  I have the config below and it seems that the login works but user data is not returned.

```js
modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios', '@nuxtjs/auth-next'],
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      social: {
        scheme: 'oauth2',
        endpoints: {
          authorization: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize',
          token: undefined,
          logout: 'http://localhost:3000/logout',
          userInfo: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
        },
        token: {
          property: 'access_token',
          type: 'Bearer',
          maxAge: 1800,
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'refresh_token',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        },
        responseType: 'code',
        grantType: 'authorization_code',
        accessType: undefined,
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/',
        logoutRedirectUri: '/',
        clientId: 'abc123',
        scope: ['user-read-private', 'user-read-email'],
        state: '',
        codeChallengeMethod: '',
        responseMode: '',
        acrValues: '',
        // autoLogout: false
      },
    },
```

My method in Login

```js
methods: {
    login() {
      this.$auth.loginWith('social')
    },
  },
```

Any help on how to get the user data would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you see the expected payload in the network tab when the module should reach the URL given to `userInfo`? Does it have the proper `Authorization` header? Also, trying this in a Postman just to be sure that this is working should be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using Postman, I was able to retrieve the user info there but still cannot get it in Nuxt.  I think it may have to do with the naming of the token property, as it seems to be looking for 'auth._token.social' rather than the default 'access_token'.  I tried using that naming in Nuxt but still no luck so I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: I also changed the endpoint 'token' value from undefined to 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'.

Comment: You cannot change `access_token` for what is needed in the `token` object of your config?